# Routing to listing/{id}

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I'm not sure how am I supposed to access individual rows via URI

this is `routes.php`

```
Route::get('listings/{id}', array('uses' => 'ListingsController@getView'));
```

But I'm actually access the listings via this URI `listings/view/{id}`

Can someone please explain why going to `listings/{id}` gives `controller not found`?

Answer (score 0):

You see an error message because the URL doesn't match a route.  "listings/view/id" != "listings/id".  Modify your route:

```
Route::get('listings/view/{id}', array('uses' => 'ListingsController@getView'));
```